# Calling a dialog in Dynamics 2011 and passing multiple recordIDs to it

Tags: javascript, dialog, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to allow the user to select one or many contacts from the contact entity, and then launch a dialog that accepts the record IDs. The idea is to add some custom configuration to the contacts.

I've currently got a custom action on a ribbon button that launches a dialog, but it only accepts one record Id. I can get access to the list of selected record Ids, thatisn't the problem, it is passing a list to the dialog using JavaScript.

I can't seem to find anything in the SDK or code snippets.
The nearest thing I found was this:

http://crmmongrel.blogspot.com/2011/06/launch-dialog-from-ribbon-button-in-crm.html

Anyone know if this is possible? I know the out of the box Send Direct E-Mail allows an email to be sent to the selected items, so I need something similar.

Should I be using dialogs or something else?

Here is a code snippet of the javascript that is called on the click of the ribbon button:

```
function LaunchModalDialog(SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences,dialogID, typeName)
{

// Get selected objects
var allItems = new Array
var allItems = SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences

// Just get first item for now as dialog only seems to accept one ID
var personId = allItems[0].Id;
personId = personId.replace(/\{/g, "");
personId = personId.replace(/\}/g, "");

// Load modal
var serverUri = Mscrm.CrmUri.create('/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx');
var mypath = serverUri + '?DialogID={' + dialogID + '}&EntityName=' + typeName + '&ObjectId={' +personId + '}';
mypath = encodeURI(mypath);

// First item from selected contacts only
window.showModalDialog(mypath);

// Reload form.
window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to specify the SelectedControlAllItemIds parameter in your Ribbon for that button. Here is a link that describes it:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crm/thread/79f959ac-0846-472f-bff1-4f5afe692a56

**--Edit--**

I'm sorry, I misunderstood - you meant launch an actual CRM Dialog, not just a normal HTML pop-up dialog window.

CRM Dialogs can't be used on multiple records by design, so you aren't going to be able to use them for this.

However, you should be able to create an HTML web resource file that you can launch from the Ribbon, passing in the SelectedControlAllItemIds parameter.  That HTML web resource would then have some javascript that would update the selected contacts using the REST endpoints (see the SDK for more information).

Hope that helps!

Comment: But how can I actually launch the dialog with multiple IDs? Is there documentation with accepted parameters for rundialog.aspx? 'http://domain/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId=%7b9A801909-29E5-4DF2-927C-337AB33D5432%7d&EntityName=contact&ObjectId=%7bA34A8144-5F9E-E011-9779-005056820889%7d
'

Comment: Does this mean I could not manage emails being send out for each updated contact through a workflow? i.e everything would end up being custom code??

Comment: No, you could still have a workflow that gets triggered off of a field update. Your Web Resource would update the fields using the REST endpoint, but that still counts as a normal field update, so any workflows triggered off of that field would still fire.

Comment: It wouldn't actually be a field update but a new role so assuming I could trigger the workflow from the creation of a role record then? Will pick through the SDK in more detail thanks

Comment: Yes assuming by role you mean a custom entity? Workflows can be triggered from the creation of the entity.

Comment: OK I've got this as far as now having a workflow that generates the emails. I can't seem to find a way of triggering this on a new 1:n relationship (Which is what my role is to the contact) Any ideas if this is possible? Seems like it would be a fairly common task!

Comment: You'll need to trigger the workflow off of the Create of the Role entity, not the Contact.

Comment: But I have a Contact and PortalRole entity. So the thing being created is actually the relationship connecting a contact with an additional PortalRole. Not sure if this is classed as an entity behind the scenes..?

Comment: Oh, so is it a Many to Many relationship between Contact and PortalRole?

Comment: A contact can have many roles so it is under the 1:n relationships from the contact instances perspective. But yes roles can be assigned to many contacts and contacts can have multiple roles. Due to my lack of understanding I thought there was an entity that sat inbetween to deal with this (thinking in SQL structure I guess)

Comment: It sounds like it is actually defined in CRM as a Many to Many though - verify by looking at the Contact entity in the Customizations area.  If this is the case, unfortunately you can't build a workflow off of associating a M2M entity.  You can build a plugin on the Associate/Disassociate messages, but that isn't fun.  You are right - behind the scenes there is a "middle" entity, but it isn't accessible through the UI. You might need to rethink your design. You could build your own M2M structure by building your own "RoleMembership" entity that has a lookup to Contact and Portal Role.

Comment: It only shows up under the 1:n relationships heading, not the n:n list. Does this mean it is possible then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4172/discussion-between-andi-and-josh-painter)

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct. The remainding issues are for a seperate discussion. Thanks!