# Dynamics CRM 2011 custom code

Tags: plugins, dialog, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm struggling to find much documentation on Dynamics CRM 2011 and have a problem. I'm not looking for code more a pointer as to the correct method of approach (workflow, dialog, custom HTML web resource etc)

I basically want something that does the following:

- Go to Contact list
- Select some contacts
- Ribbon action opens  a box that allows me
  to select a custom role from a drop down list (source is a dynamics
  entity)
- Select a radio box for either add or remove role
- Save the changes, this will add or remove a role from the contact and also send an email to that contact

I know how to get a list of selected recordIDs but I am not sure if I should be calling a dialog or a custom HTML page with JS.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600066/calling-a-dialog-in-dynamics-2011-and-passing-multiple-recordids-to-it/7600740#comment9293010_7600740

You need to be using a HTML web resource with javascript that uses the REST endpoint.

Comment: I tried to approach it differently to try and attract some more interest.

Comment: How many roles are we talking about? Is Role a custom entity that is required for some other reason? Do you need to send an email to the contact only when they have been added to the role or also when they have been removed?

Comment: Just when they are given a new role. Would I call a HTML resource directly from the ribbon action then?

Comment: What about my other questions?  Help me help you. :)

Comment: 1 role will be added or removed at one time for 1 or many contacts. We have a dialog currently where you select the role, then if you want to add or remove it. So I not have to replicate all that manually, getting roles drop down etc in a html web resource and call that from the js behind the ribbon?

Comment: Are there 3 total roles? 5? 10? 100? Yes, you will have to recreate all of that with web resources (html and js) unless we can think of another way, but not without you answering my questions. :) Again, what is a "Role"?  Custom entity?

Comment: Sorry yes it is a custom entity and there will be N roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the solution was to create a Ribbon item that accepted the selected Guids from the contact list.

Then read those in from a web resource (Silverlight) which called into the sdk and created / removed the records accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This may not work at all for your scenario but it is worth thinking out of the box sometimes. This would only work if you have a small number of roles and the roles don't change that often.

Add checkboxes on the Contact, one for each role.  Build workflows that fire on update of those checkboxes that send your emails.  Now users can quickly edit lots of Contact Roles by using the Multi-Edit feature.

The benefit of this approach is it is a "no code" solution and it is very easy for the User since it uses out-of-the-box functionality.  The downside is that you need to maintain those checkboxes.  But it may be easier than writing a bunch of web resources and javascript!

Answer (score 1):

I have assembled a list of bookmarks on the subject [here](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l#!threadID=Gqeotch81NKA/BDQJn3woQgbCzoqQm). I hope the link works.
[Gareth Tucker's site](http://gtcrm.wordpress.com) is specially interesting.

Comment: This is just a huge list of links and some general info about Ribbon editing. Please provide specific, helpful answers.

Comment: @Josh: Very large question, very large answer !