# Calling a child dialog and passing in input parameters

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I've read a bunch of articles on how to call dialogs from javascript and integrate them into a ribbon button, but I am running into a problem where I need to do all that AND pass in a string as an input parameter (to a child dialog?).

Is this possible? Would I have to modify the calling url of the dialog?

I've read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600066/calling-a-dialog-in-dynamics-2011-and-passing-multiple-recordids-to-it) about calling dialogs with the SelectedControlAllItemsId, which is almost what I need.

Ideally I would open the form of the parent entity, click on one of the subgrids in the left hand navigation, then select some of the related/associated entities, click the ribbon button and wait for the dialog or workflow to chew through all of those Ids.

Is it possible to capture these selected items using SelectedControlAllItemsId, then pass that string to a child dialog so it can then call another workflow? Or should I capture that string, store it in the calling record via REST and then let a workflow run on a field-trigger?

The end result is that I must run a custom workflow and manipulate the parent record + the selected related records. I have already written the workflow, but I do not know how to trigger it the way I want.

Perhaps there is something I am overlooking? Is there a way to call a custom bit of code directly from javascript and let it work the rest of the way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how an interactive dialog should deal with a collection of records. Surely that would require sequential iterations of the dialog, as the user processes each record? As you will see [from the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509067.aspx#StartDialog) (and discussed in your linked thread), it is only possible to run a *dialog* against a single record.

A workflow is a different matter.
 - Custom ribbon button, using `SelectedControlAllItemsId`
 - Supporting JScript handler should iterate `SelectedControlAllItemsId`
 - Each iteration should issue an `ExecuteWorkflowRequest` using the current item id and based on [code such as this](http://mileyja.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/execute-workflow-using-net-or-jscript.html) (which issues an `ExecuteWorkflowRequest` from JScript

Remember that the workflow request is asynchronous so you can just send all the requests one after another rather than waiting for the outcome of each request.